# How to make a dragged div land on the position it was dragged to, and how to remove the the "globe"-img on drag in html drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-drag-div-ddkfg9?file=/src/index.js

If you run the above codesandbox .. you'll see a div in the top left corner which is draggable. But when you drag this div, it:

1. always returns to top-left of the page on drag-end
2. there is a "globe" image that shows up beside the pointer while dragging

How do I:

1. make the div take the position it was dragged to?
2. show a cursor-grabbing type of cursor while drag is in progress?

Comment: Looks like you need to [define a dropzone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#define_a_drop_zone). However, if you only want to move the box around on the screen then you don't need drag and drop for that.

Comment: I tried moving the box around with mousedown, mousmove etc events ... The tricky part is mouseout, which causes dragging to stop if mouse is moved too quickly.

Comment: I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yuscekv/) that shows how to move items around on the screen.  Drag and drop is more complex than just moving an item on the screen. It's usually used to initiate some process like uploading a file or reorganizing a table.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Yogi's comment, was able to get a proof-of-concept of drag-and-place in react working https://codesandbox.io/s/react-drag-div-forked-ymy3t7?file=/src/index.js